# Trigger doesn't work(ORA-04088 error during execution of trigger)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have DB of selling tickets for trains. I have table `Ticket` and table `Cancel`(here are canceled tickets). I have already written a trigger, when if I add some ticket to table `Cancel` then this ticket sets free in table Ticket(Client_id attribute = NULL).

But I want to write new one: "if I have canceled ticket(Client_id = NULL in table Ticket), and then when I update ticket and sets Client_id = 'some_number'(e.g. Client_id = 5), then I should delete this ticket from `Cancel` table.
Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Buy_Cancel
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON TICKET
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN(old.CLIENT_ID IS NULL)
DECLARE 
  rowAmmount INTEGER;
BEGIN 
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO rowAmmount
    FROM CANCEL c JOIN TICKET t ON c.TICKET_ID = t.TICKET_ID
    WHERE t.TICKET_ID = :OLD.TICKET_ID;
  IF rowAmmount > 0 THEN 
    DELETE FROM CANCEL c
      WHERE c.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID;
  END IF;
END;
```

When I run a query:

```
UPDATE TICKET t
  SET t.CLIENT_ID = 5
  WHERE t.TICKET_ID = 2;
```

it cause such errors:

```
ORA-04091: table MYDB.TICKET is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "MYDB.BUY_CANCEL", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MYDB.BUY_CANCEL' SQL6.sql 2 8
```

Comment: Not for nothing, but "CANCEL" is not a good name for a database table.  In any case, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996748/mutating-trigger-function-may-not-see-it-error-during-execution-of-trigger?rq=1) which may provide some insight into the error message you're receiving.

Comment: I deleted my second trigger, so this is the only trigger in my DB. But the errors stay the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I quite understand your logic, but the error is because you're querying the `ticket` table within a trigger on that table. You don't need to - the join doesn't seem to be adding anything, since you already have the ticket ID:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Buy_Cancel
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON TICKET
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN(old.CLIENT_ID IS NULL)
DECLARE 
  rowAmmount INTEGER;
BEGIN 
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO rowAmmount
    FROM CANCEL c
    WHERE c.TICKET_ID = :OLD.TICKET_ID;
  IF rowAmmount > 0 THEN 
    DELETE FROM CANCEL c
      WHERE c.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID;
  END IF;
END;
```

There isn't much point doing the query at all though, really; just dpong the delete on its own. would work - it won't error if there are no matching rows, so it would simplify it quite a bit. And you're using `:old` in the `select`, and `:new` in the delete; that's fine if they're the same (which is likely if that's the primary key), but looks odd anyway.

Comment: Yes, this works. I just didn't know that I can't query Ticket table within a trigger on that table. As I understand, I can't query the table, because I change data in that table? I admit that it's odd to use :OLD and then :NEW, but in my case there is no difference, because i'm changing only Client_id, not Ticket_id. Just forgot to write in trigger update OF CLIENT_ID;